# GitHub.com hosted repository, prevent branch deletion

Tags: github, webhooks

My friend has a GitHub.com hosted repository and had asked me to assist in setting up a webhook to prevent his "test" branch from being deleted. I've done this in BitBucket which is extremely simple.

But how does one go about doing this for a hosted GitHub.com repository? There is a webhooks section, but it involves speaking to an external URL, which we don't have.

I've had a difficult time finding documentation regarding this for a Github.com hosted repository, but plenty for a locally hosted GitHub instance.

TIA.

Comment: Also, we need the webhook to execute for all users. Not for just for any individual user.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just got the answer from GitHub staff directly...

https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/